# How to parse a column from one file in mutiple other columns and concatenate the output?

Tags: awk, grep

I have one file like this:

```
head allGenes.txt
ENSG00000128274
ENSG00000094914
ENSG00000081760
ENSG00000158122
ENSG00000103591
...
```

and I have a multiple files named like this *.v7.egenes.txt in the current directory. For example one file looks like this:

```
head Stomach.v7.egenes.txt
ENSG00000238009 RP11-34P13.7  1  89295 129223  - 2073 1.03557 343.245
ENSG00000237683   AL627309.1  1 134901 139379  - 2123 1.02105 359.907
ENSG00000235146 RP5-857K21.2  1 523009 530148  + 4098 1.03503 592.973
ENSG00000231709 RP5-857K21.1  1 521369 523833  - 4101 1.07053 559.642
ENSG00000223659 RP5-857K21.5  1 562757 564390  - 4236 1.05527 595.015
ENSG00000237973 hsa-mir-6723  1 566454 567996  + 4247 1.05299 592.876
```

I would like to get lines from all *.v7.egenes.txt files that match any entry in allGenes.txt

I tried using:

```
grep -w -f allGenes.txt *.v7.egenes.txt > output.txt
```

but this takes forever to complete. Is there is any way to do this in awk or?

Comment: how many files are you processing? how many lines in each file?

Comment: try changing `-w` to `-F`. Unlikely that changing to `awk` will run any faster. Maybe you need to read about `gnu-parallel` or `xargs`. Good luck.

Comment: how many lines in allGenes.txt? how many lines in the other files? assuming these are some pretty large files ... have you thought about kicking off several `grep` sessions in parallel (each processing a different set of files)?

Comment: do you mean to run this:  grep -F -f allGenes.txt *.v7.egenes.txt > output.txt

Comment: @anamaria yes, try that new `grep` combination; the question is whether the `-F` is more efficient than `-w`; and add the `-h` flag to suppress the printing of the file names

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without knowing the size of the files, but assuming the host has enough memory to hold `allGenes.txt` in memory, one `awk` solution comes to mind:

```
awk 'NR==FNR { gene[$1] ; next } ( $1 in gene )' allGenes.txt *.v7.egenes.txt > output.txt
```

Where:

- `NR==FNR` - this test only matches the first file to be processed (`allGenes.txt`)
- `gene[$1]` - store each gene as an index in an associative array
- `next` stop processing and go to next line in the file
- `$1 in gene` - applies to all lines in all other files; if the first field is found to be an index in our associative array then we print the current line

I wouldn't expect this to run any/much faster than the `grep` solution the OP is currently using (especially with shelter's suggestion to use `-F` instead of `-w`), but it should be relatively quick to test and see ....

Comment: I run your awk command I I got: awk: cmd. line:1: fatal: cannot open file `*.v7.egens.txt' for reading (No such file or directory). I run the above grep command with -F modification and I got in output names of the files appended to the first column, is there is any chance to remove that in that grep command, it looks like this: Adipose_Subcutaneous.v7.egenes.txt:ENSG00000188976

Comment: for the `grep` solution add the `-h` flag to *not* display file names; for the `awk` error ... are  you running the `awk` command from the same directory where the `*.v7.egens.txt` files are located?  are there any files that match that string - `*.v7.egens.txt`?

Comment: sorry, my mistake ... typo ... fixed, try again ?

Comment: about the same time as grep with -F

Comment: and was `grep -F` (much) faster than your original `grep` solution?

Comment: yes grep -F was much faster than my original grep -w -f solution

Comment: `gene[$1]` actually defines an array element (`gene[$1]=""`) for each entry called with and wastes memory. Instead use `($i in gene)`.

Comment: @JamesBrown; wasn't quite following your comment; found [this item](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Reference-to-Elements.html#Reference-to-Elements) ... so just *testing* for a field in an array will create an array item, right?  I've updated the answer with what I think you were suggesting ...

Answer (score 1):

GNU Parallel has a whole section dedicated to grepping n lines for m regular expressions:
https://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/man.html#EXAMPLE:-Grepping-n-lines-for-m-regular-expressions

Answer (score 0):

You could try with a while read loop :

```
#!/bin/bash

while read -r line; do
  grep -rnw Stomach.v7.egenes.txt -e "$line" >> output.txt
done < allGenes.txt
```

So here tell the while loop to read all the lines from the allGenes.txt, and for each line, check whether there are matching lines in the egenes file. Would that do the trick?

EDIT :

New version :

```
#!/bin/bash

for name in $(cat allGenes.txt); do
  grep -rnw *v7.egenes.txt* -e $name >> output.txt
done
```

Comment: but how to do this in all files in current directory whose names look like this .v7.egenes.txt?

Comment: I have to process 44 files

Comment: There you go, added the edit, so it will check whether a line in allGenes.txt exists in any of the files matching the *v7.egenes.txt* expression. Goes without saying you need to run the script inside the directory where the files reside

Comment: thanks, but this has been running for more than 30 min I wonder if there is a speedier solution...

Comment: the loop completed and I tried to load it into R but I got this: Warning message:
In fread("output.txt", fill = TRUE) :
  Stopped early on line 28335. Expected 33 fields but found 42.

Comment: fwiw, the repeated scans of the `*.v7.egenes.txt` files is going to slow this down (compared to the `grep` and `awk` solutions which scan each `*.v7.egenes.txt` file just once)